# Working with Nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I have the below query which returns what products are on what orderID.

```
SELECT  P.Name,
STUFF   (( SELECT ' | ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(22) , SOD.SalesOrderID)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
        WHERE
        P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
        as Orders
FROM Production.Product P
```

However, I am having trouble with the 'Nulls'.  I've tried isnull is different parts of the code as well as a case statement but can't seem to figure where it would go.

If anyone can give me any help that would be great.

Comment: What is getting nulled that shouldn't be?  Could you show a little sample data and output you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problematic `NULL`s are in `SOD.SalesOrderId`.

```
One way to handle them is by filtering them out:

SELECT  P.Name,
STUFF   (( SELECT ' | ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(22) , SOD.SalesOrderID)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
        WHERE
        P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID and SOD.SalesOrderId is not null
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
        as Orders
FROM Production.Product P
```

Another way is to convert them to some acceptable representation:

```
SELECT  P.Name,
STUFF   (( SELECT ' | ' +  coalesce(CONVERT(VARCHAR(22) , SOD.SalesOrderID), '<NULL>')
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
        WHERE
        P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
        as Orders
FROM Production.Product P
```

EDIT:

The `NULL`s are being returned because there is no match in `SalesOrderDetail` for the records.  What would you want returned in this case?

To find those products:

```
select p.*
from Production.Product p left outer join
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
     on p.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
where sod.ProductId is null;
```

If you want to filter them out, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<either of the above queries>) t
where t.Orders is not NULL
```

EDIT II:

If you want blanks to be returned, then wrap `coalesce()` around the value:

```
SELECT  P.Name,
coalesce(STUFF   (( SELECT ' | ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(22) , SOD.SalesOrderID)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
        WHERE
        P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, ''), '')
        as Orders
FROM Production.Product P
```

Comment: Hi,

Both queries still returned nulls.

http://oi42.tinypic.com/2v2e6fs.jpg

I think the nulls are appearing as they are part of a left join and I'm not sure if it's possible to filter them out at all

Comment: Hello,

I would like a blank ' '  to be returned.  It's no big deal, it's for purley educational purposes.

Comment: Brilliant!  I was sure I tried isnull/coalesce in every possible part of the code.

Thank you so much for helping me with this.  Marked as answered.